# How do I return a Twig template inside the build method of a block class?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

Am new to Drupal and this week I learned quite a bit about module development, and for today the case is:

For my new module, I create a custom block that renders a markup, and from the folder structure, the class looks like this:

Note: fax is the module's machine name.

fax/src/Plugin/Block/FaxBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\fax\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;

/**
 * Provides a 'Fax' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "fax_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Fax block"),
 * )
 */
class FaxBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

    public function build() {

        return array(
            '#markup' => $this->t('This is just a text initially'),
        );  
    }

}
```

I know that in the build method we can also return a form for instance:

```
 public function build() {
    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\rsvplist\Form\RSVPForm');
 }
```

And that we can put HTML inside the array if we want.

Question: how can I instead create a template a return that inside the array?

so, instead of returning a markup like this:

```
'#markup' => $this->t('This is just a text initially'),
```

I could have a template somewhere:

```
<div>
  <p>This is a great example</p>
</div>
```

and then return the template in the build function.

How can I return a template inside the build method of my block?

Comment: See [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your modules `*.module` file you must implement [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x) like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function fax_theme() {
  return [
    'fax_custom_theme' => [
      'variables' => [
        'test' => NULL, # Makes the {{ test }} variable available in the template.
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then you can return this in your block:

```
$test = 'My custom variable';
return [
  '#theme' => 'fax_custom_theme',
  '#test' => $test, # Assigns a value to the {{ test }} variable.
];
```

This makes the `{{ test }}` variable available in your theme.

Then add your template to the module under `fax/templates/fax-custom-theme.html.twig`.

Template names are using dashes instead of undercores.

Comment: Comments have been deleted. Please don't use them for a continuous back-and-forth. That is not the purpose of comments.